# Downloading games to PSVita from other stores than the Japanese

Tags: psn, ps-vita

Is it possible to download PSVita games to an imported device without using a Japanese account? That is, before its launched in EU for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the US and EU stores are not live. Attempting to access the PSN store with a US profile on a Vita as of 12/31/2010 will encounter a cannot connect error until they are launched along side the Vita rollouts in those markets.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that any other countries will launch their stores prior to their country's release.  As the Playstation Vita has not officially released in countries other than Japan, I highly doubt this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for sharing my suspisions, but its not enough. I need someone who has tried, and i bet there is by now.